# What does genki (from genki dama) means?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, japanese-language

So from the previews from the following episodes we get to know that

(spoilers)

> 18 and 17 donates energy to Goku's Genki Dama. People speculated that since they have unlimited energy, Goku could get to form an extremely powerful Genki Dama thanks to their energy but no, because it's been said by some fans that ki energy (attack energy) is different than Genki energy Goku uses for the Genki Dama bomb.

So what does Genki (from Genki Dama) mean?

Answer (score 5):

http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_Bomb:

> Spirit Bomb (元気玉 Genki Dama, lit. "Energy Sphere")

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/元氣](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%83%E6%B0%A3)

> From Middle Chinese compound 元氣 (ngjwon khjɨjH, literally “first, fundamental, source + vapor, spirit, energy”) In Chinese cosmology, this represented the fundamental force that permeates all matter and life. Early Japanese borrowed this word and meaning. Later, this spelling was conflated with the meaning of homophone 減気 (genki, “recovery from illness”), adding in the modern senses related to healthy and wellness.

Comment: yeah, but what I am really asking what's the difference between genki and ki because ki also means energy. So genki needs to have a slightly different meaning than just energy, and it's simplified when translated, I suppose.

Comment: @Pablo - Ask that as another question, and then comment about it here, then I'll answer. 'Cause changing your question right now, is gonna invalidate this...

Answer (score 0):

Genki means Energy in Japanese.

Ki does not mean energy, it’s used as judging spirit power, more or less, kinda like how you size up someone for a fight. The feeling you get from your opponent before you fight type of deal, for lack of a more realistic way to look at it.

Comment: Genki Sushi... yum

Answer (score -1):

Also, Genki Dama doesn’t actually translate to ‘Spirit Bomb’ either, it’s really ‘Energy Ball’, if we are being honest. ‍♂️

Yamcha used to use it before Goku ever did, it was one of his signature moves. Goku just learned how to do it on a planetary level from Kaio Sama, or King Kai in America.

America twists the translation to make things sound better for English, that’s why it’s usually better to watch Subbed things, they say more than what America gives most of the time.

It’s almost better if you try to learn Japanese, you can catch more.

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. if you have more to add you should [edit your original answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/53205/edit) instead of posting a second answer